# Question: Do these transformation matrices commute?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analytic-geometry, transformation, coordinate-systems

Let $\;\{ \vec i,\vec j,\vec k \}\;$ be the standard co-ordinate system of $\;\mathbb R^3\;$ and consider these two matrices:

- $\;A=\begin{pmatrix}
       0\;\;0\;-1\\0\;\;\frac{1}{x_2}\;\;0\\1\;\;\;0\;\;\;0\\
       \end{pmatrix}\;$
- $\;B\;$ a $\;3\times 3\;$ orthonormal matrix such that $\;B \vec i=\vec y_1\;,\;B \vec j=\vec y_2\;,\;B \vec k=\vec y_3\;$ where $\;\{ y_1,y_2,y_3 \}\;$ is another orthonormal system of $\;\mathbb R^3\;$. *Note:* The two co-ordinate systems have the same origin.$\;B\;$ represents a rotation matrix. To be more specific, $\;B\;$ is a counter-clockwise rotation by $\;\hat \theta\;$ about the $\;x-axis\;$.

**QUESTION:** Do $\;A,B^T\;$ commute in the sense that $\;AB^T=B^TA\;$?

**My Attempt:**

I wrote $\;A\vec i=-\vec k\;,\;A\vec j=1\;,\;A\vec k=\vec i\;$ and thought it is sufficient to show $\;B^TA\vec i=AB^T\vec i\;$,$\;B^TA\vec j=AB^T\vec j\;$,$\;B^TA\vec k=AB^T\vec k\;$. However I got stuck in the very beginning:

$\;B^TA\vec i=B^T(-\vec k)\;$ **How should I proceed?**

I'm having a really hard time getting my head around this. To be honest, I'm not sure if the matrices commute in first place. And if they do, I don't know how to prove it.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Matrices usually don't commute. Can you write down the matrix for $B$ and just multiply by $A$ both ways.

Comment: Remember that you can write $B$ explicitly as $B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 &\cos(\hat\theta) & -\sin(\hat\theta) \\ 0 &\sin(\hat\theta) & \cos(\hat \theta)\end{pmatrix}$ and just compute explicitly $AB^T$ and $B^TA$.

Comment: @Cyclone I'll try this and I'll come back

Comment: @Cyclone Thanks a lot for your comment. You helped me a lot!